# Condition of our Fibonacci challenge

Tags: discussion

Let's face it: [our Fibonacci challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence) is not great.

To quote a [recent effort of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131513/fibtraction-fibonacci-but-with-subtraction) to improve on the situation:

> ...the challenge is old and outdated; is severely under-specified; allows for two types of solutions; has answers that don't have easy ways to try online; and in general, is lacking of answers. Essentially, in my opinion, it doesn't serve as a good "catalogue" of solutions.

But what can we do about it? Here are a few solutions I thought of:

- <s>Make an "almost Fibonacci challenge"</s> Nope, [didn't go down well](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131513/fibtraction-fibonacci-but-with-subtraction).
- Make a new, canonical question

  - What should we do with the answers to the old question?
  - Can we merge the two questions?
- "Bump" the old question fitted to our current standards

  - How can we attract more activity?

Comment: Our current consensus is to allow newer languages to compete, however, I feel we should update this challenge in particular to be a catalogue.

Comment: @ATaco I agree that the fact that newer languages can now compete is beneficial, however I still think the challenge will still not receive any activity.

Comment: "How can we attract more activity?"  Do we really need more activity?  I don't see any reason to encourage users to answer a question that already has 173 answers.  I don't see any reason to discourage users either.

Comment: @ATaco, what do you mean by "*update ... to be a catalogue*"? Is that just adding a stack snippet to summarise the answers or something more?

Comment: [I actually wrote up a new spec two years ago.](https://gist.github.com/m-ender/b77bbf2c02e48b50becd)

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything wrong with the current challenge.  I updated it to flexible IO a little while ago and added an actual specification.  The entire body of the question is actually pretty modern.  I even asked around if people thought it was clear and received only positive feedback.  That doesn't mean its perfect but I would not say that the question body is old or outdated, and I am perfectly willing to take responsibility for any land all problems present in the writeup of the question.

I think that your complaint that it is "in general lacking answers" is simply false, as I mentioned in my comment it has 173 answers, which is *a lot* of answers.  If this is a lack of answers I don't think anything can be done.  Fibonacci is probably not interesting to the majority of users at this point and I don't see everyone rushing to add hundreds more answers anytime soon.  If you want more answers you can post an answer yourself or bounty the question.  Reposting the question is a surefire way to get *less* answers than there already are.

I also think that it is not "severely lacking" in specification (A little bit biased because I wrote the current specification, so if I thought it was incomplete I would have added to it).  Any holes in the specification could be fixed with edits.

I don't think allowing for two types of solutions is a bad thing, flexible IO is in general *good* for challenges even though one is less conventional I think it adds to the challenge.  The only reason I could see to not allow a method of output is to prevent abuse.  I don't think there is anyway to abuse the current method and I think answers that use it are no less valid than answers that use a traditional method.

I don't understand your comment about try it online, so I wont touch that.

Overall I think the question is fine.  Minor edits can be made, but I don't think we need to do anything drastic, like make a new question or overhaul the existing challenge.